# Ordering objects by foreignkey field and not foreignkey count

Tags: django, django-views

I am making a request and a voting feature for the request:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Vote(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote_type = models.BooleanField()
```

I would like to order requests by the total vote counts in descending order by substracting different vote_type's (True/False) for each request. Meaning order requests with highest number of votes to lowest number of votes.

I can order by the vote this way:

```
Request.objects.order_by('-vote')
```

But this just gives me which request has highest number of foreign key count, and not the actual vote count.

I can get the actual vote counts for a request like this:

```
def get_vote_count(obj):
    return obj.vote_set.filter(vote_type=True).count() - obj.vote_set.filter(vote_type=False).count()
```

But I can't figure out how to achieve this when getting all the requests and ordering them in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by using the [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).

Try this:

```
from django.db import models

Request.objects.annotate(
    num_of_true_vote_type=models.Count(
        models.Case(When(vote__vote_type=True, then=1), output_field=models.IntegerField())
    ),
    num_of_false_vote_type=models.Count(
        models.Case(When(vote__vote_type=False, then=1), output_field=models.IntegerField())
    ),
    difference=models.F('num_of_true_vote_type') - models.F('num_of_false_vote_type')
).order_by('-difference')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) for this

```
r = Request.objects.filter(approved=True, vote__vote_type=True).annotate(total_vote=Count('vote'))
```

this will give you `QuerySet` of `Request` with `approved=True`. `annotate` part will give you extra attribut `total_vote` to every `Request` object with value count of all related `Vote` that have `vote_type=True`.

Do not forget that its `QuerySet` so to see how many `Vote` with `vote_type=True` for "first" `Request` you do `r.first().total_vote`